# Как изменить очередь в html на WordPress?

Tags: html, wordpress

Мне нужно поставить div с классом sidebar перед div с классом content. Сейчас он стоит под ним. На Wordpess html генерируется из php, что нужно изменить, не знаю.
Это нужно для того, чтобы сайдбар при маленьких экранах всегда был выше контента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это, похоже, woocommerce. Так?

Comment: А если просто css flex order?

Comment: Да, там woocommerce подключен.

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите файл `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php`, скопируйте его в папку темы: `wp-content/themes/ваша-тема/woocommerce/archive-product.php`. Если такой папки нет, ее надо создать.

В нем переставьте блок

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
?>
```

наверх, после

```
get_header( 'shop' ); ?>
```

Comment: В моем случие wp-content/themes/ваша-тема/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php нет папки woocommerce поетому скопировал файл в templates но появился белый екран
https://prnt.sc/foebxh
https://prnt.sc/foef2p

Comment: надо создать такую папку! И я поправил ответ - папка в теме чуть другая

Comment: Какая версия WooCommerce? Покажите файл archive-product.php

Comment: Версия 3.0.8 / 
файл archive-product.php https://pastebin.com/nasFesxg

Comment: Вы header с footer не путайте.

Comment: Уже правильно переставил https://pastebin.com/nasFesxg
Но сайдбар опять идеть вторым http://prntscr.com/fogfgw
FTP: http://prntscr.com/fogg9u

Answer (score 0):

Доступ в админку есть?
Если есть - всё достаточно просто, заходите в админку, в панели идете в редактор кода темы, находите файлы sidebar, page, header.
Ищете необходимые вам блоки и переставляете местами.
Желательно знать, какой шаблон используется для той страницы, которую вы показываете

Comment: Это WooCommerce, на 99%. А там все не так.

Comment: Захожу в редактор, этих файлов нет, перехожу в родительскую тему:
http://prntscr.com/fodg6f
Там есть sidebar.php, page.php, header.php
http://prntscr.com/fodiai
http://prntscr.com/fodj0g
https://pastebin.com/C8w5RfHk
Как эти блоки переставить местами? 
flex order преминял, content_wrap задал display:flex; а sidebar order:-1; но тогда content ламаеться.